# How can i create a multi user program in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have a form which accepts product details as well displays the details that was entered, iam using a bean  to store and display back. my problem is when i load the same page from different machine the previous users data is visible.

Can some one help me out...
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  >
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
</h:head>
<h:body>


    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o"
            styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
        >

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
            #{o.orderNo}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
            #{o.productName}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
            #{o.price}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
            #{o.qty}

        </h:column>

        <h:column>

            <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>

            <h:commandLink value="Delete" 
                               action="#{order.deleteAction(o)}" />

        </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

        <h3>Enter Order</h3>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Order No :</td>
            <td><h:inputText size="10" value="#{order.orderNo}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name :</td>
            <td><h:inputText size="20" value="#{order.productName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity :</td>
            <td><h:inputText size="5" value="#{order.price}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price :</td>
            <td><h:inputText size="10" value="#{order.qty}" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{order.addAction}" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>



package Bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name="order")
@RequestScoped
public class PodMasterBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String orderNo;
private String productName;
private BigDecimal price;
private int qty;
private static final ArrayList<Order> orderList =
        new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(
        new Order("A0001", "Intel CPU",
        new BigDecimal("700.00"), 1),
        new Order("A0002", "Harddisk 10TB",
        new BigDecimal("500.00"), 2),
        new Order("A0003", "Dell Laptop",
        new BigDecimal("11600.00"), 8),
        new Order("A0004", "Samsung LCD",
        new BigDecimal("5200.00"), 3),
        new Order("A0005", "A4Tech Mouse",
        new BigDecimal("100.00"), 10)));

public ArrayList<Order> getOrderList() {

    return orderList;

}

public String addAction() {

    Order order = new Order(this.getOrderNo(), this.getProductName(), this.getPrice(), this.getQty());

    orderList.add(order);
    return null;
}

public String deleteAction(Order order) {

    orderList.remove(order);
    return null;
}


public String getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}


public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}


public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}


public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}


public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}


public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}


public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}



/// new class
public static class Order {

    private String orderNo;
    private String productName;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int qty;

    public Order(String orderNo, String productName,
            BigDecimal price, int qty) {
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getOrderNo() {
        return orderNo;
    }


    public void setOrderNo(String orderNo) {
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
    }


    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }


    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }


    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }


    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the scope of your managed bean? If it is requestScoped? then it should not happen I think

Comment: Iam using SessionScoped and ManagedBean

Comment: Are the usrs logged in from different machine's are really different?

Comment: Yes. i have deployed in glassfish server and accessing from different machine

Comment: No, I mean to say you have used username and password to log in for different users right? If they are SessionScoped, then every user must create a new session.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar don't mix login sessions and JSF related sessions. They are totally different terms.

Comment: iam executing the same file from different machine... can you let me know how to open this file in different session. (some article to go through ...:) iam new to this)

Comment: @XtremeBiker, I am also beginner to jsf, can you please elaborate the difference between these two sessions?

Comment: The first one is the session related with your username/pass. It's something you manage in your webapp by yourself. The JSF session is related with the framework itself (HttpSession) and it'll be different even you login into the application using the same username/pass in two different machines.

Comment: so if i open a jsf file from different machine it would be in a differnt JSF session and the data of first machine should not be be visible in second machine ?

Comment: JSF file does not exist. There are JSF beans, whith different scopes. The data from an application scoped bean will be visible for the whole application. However, the data from a session scoped bean is available only for the current JSF session.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBiker, In my bean i have used SessionScoped do i  need to do some other checking(based on session id) . so that the data entered in one machine is not visible in the other.

Comment: Absolutelly no. That's the aim of having the different scopes.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker. let me know what to do. :( SessionScoped and RequestScoped bean data is visible on other machine

Comment: Without example code I can do nothing. You should provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Please learn what `static` does. This is a basic Java problem, not a JSF one. Please learn basic Java before continuing with JSF, or it will end up in a disaster and you would unfairly blame JSF instead of yourself for being the cause.

Comment: sorry got the error. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `static` variables implies that every single instance of that bean will have that value in the whole application, even the been is reinstantiated for each request. You are adding an order to that list every time you execute `addAction()`, so it will have consecuences for every end user.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the thread as answered (✓)